# UICell problem iPhone while Scrolling tableView

Tags: iphone

My Current Problem Related links are one of below.

---

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a65dae5f4a.png>http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.a65dae5f4a.png alt="Free Image Hosting by FreeImageHosting.net">

[url=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a65dae5f4a.png][img]http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.a65dae5f4a.png[/img][/url]

[url=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a65dae5f4a.png][img=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.a65dae5f4a.png][/url]

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/>http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a65dae5f4a.png border=0 alt="Free Image Hosting">

[url=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/][img]http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a65dae5f4a.png[/img][/url]

[url=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/][img=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a65dae5f4a.png][/url]

---

I have implemented following code, to my Table view,

```
enter code here
```

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// customizing cell
student *t=[studentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
CGRect label1Frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 25);
CGRect label2Frame=CGRectMake(10, 33, 290, 25);
CGRect label3Frame=CGRectMake(10, 56, 290, 25);
UILabel *lbltmp;
lbltmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label1Frame];  // name
lbltmp.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
lbltmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbltmp.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
lbltmp.text=t.stuName;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbltmp];
[lbltmp release];

lbltmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label2Frame]; // roll no & address
lbltmp.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
lbltmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbltmp.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i - %@",t.stuNo,t.stuAddress];
lbltmp.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbltmp];
[lbltmp release];

lbltmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label3Frame]; // city & pin
lbltmp.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
lbltmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbltmp.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",t.stuCity,t.stuPin];
lbltmp.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbltmp];
[lbltmp release];
//----------------------------------
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
```

}

If I implement the code as described above, problem occurs as described in above images.

If I implement following code, no problem occurs.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

// customizing cell
student *t=[studentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
CGRect label1Frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 25);
CGRect label2Frame=CGRectMake(10, 33, 290, 25);
CGRect label3Frame=CGRectMake(10, 56, 290, 25);
UILabel *lbltmp;
lbltmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label1Frame];  // name
lbltmp.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
lbltmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbltmp.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
lbltmp.text=t.stuName;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbltmp];
[lbltmp release];

lbltmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label2Frame]; // roll no & address
lbltmp.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
lbltmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbltmp.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i - %@",t.stuNo,t.stuAddress];
lbltmp.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbltmp];
[lbltmp release];

lbltmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label3Frame]; // city & pin
lbltmp.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
lbltmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbltmp.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",t.stuCity,t.stuPin];
lbltmp.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbltmp];
[lbltmp release];
//----------------------------------
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
return cell;
```

}

**Implementing the above code means, recreating the each table cell while user scrolls the tableView. It may slow down your application & it isn't the correct solution,**

Because In my application I have thousands of students & if I create each cell while scroll My Application may hang. What Should be the solution? Help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're adding subviews on top of already-added subviews when the cells are recycled.

One way to fix this: subclass `UITableViewCell` and give it pointers to `UILabel`s for the text you want to change.  Then when the cell is recycled, you can just access those properties, instead of re-adding new subviews.

Reference: [An Apple doc on table view cells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is as follows:

Implement following method to your `tableViewCotroller`

```
-(UITableViewCell*)getCellContentView:(NSString*)cellIdentifier
{
}
```

For example I have Implemented following

```
-(UITableViewCell*)getCellContentView:(NSString*)cellIdentifier
{
    CGRect photoFrame=CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 60);
    CGRect label1Frame=CGRectMake(90, 10, 290, 25);
    CGRect label2Frame=CGRectMake(90, 30, 290, 25);
    CGRect label3Frame=CGRectMake(90, 50, 290, 25);

    UITableViewCell *cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80) reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UILabel *tmp;
    tmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label1Frame];
    tmp.tag=1;
    tmp.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    tmp.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tmp];
    [tmp release];

    tmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label2Frame];
    tmp.tag=2;
    tmp.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=0;
    tmp.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    tmp.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tmp];
    [tmp release];

    tmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label3Frame];
    tmp.tag=3;
    tmp.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=0;
    tmp.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    tmp.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tmp];
    [tmp release];

    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:photoFrame];
    imgView.tag=4;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];

    return cell;
}
```

I have also called above method form `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // customizing cell
    student *t=[studentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

    UILabel *lb1=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lb2=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *lb3=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    NSString *dtlOne=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enr.No - %i, %@",t.stuNo,t.stuAddress];
    NSString *dtlTwo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@.",t.stuCity,t.stuPin];
    lb1.text=t.stuName;
    lb2.text=dtlOne;
    lb3.text=dtlTwo;    

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    return cell;
}
```

That works perfectly, and I can also use my custom content view in my cell.